# Applescript Tell Application of Specific Instance

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, script

If I have 2 instances of one application running, and I want to target one of them by their PID to run an Applescript snippet, how would I go about that? I have the PID of the instance I want to target, but if I run the following, it will execute on whichever instance was started last.

```
tell application "/Applications/Adobe After Effects CC 2018/Adobe After Effects CC 2018.app" to DoScript "alert()"
```

Is there a way to either set an instance as the "Frontmost" so it get's targeted, or get an application by PID and tell that one specifically?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @GrahamMiln 10.12.6

Comment: Do you have any programming experience? I expect a combination of Scripting Bridge and a small application would get this done. This is beyond Ask Different but if you can justify a fee, please get in touch.

Comment: @GrahamMiln Yes I do, the application I'm using this in is a Javascript Electron app, but I only need to use AppleScript for this specific call into After Effects, since that's the only way to communicate with the app directly from an external app other than building a plugin/extension to interpret (which is possible just not ideal). I don't have a ton of experience with AppleScript, but I'll check out ScriptingBridge. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer and provided a few links about Scripting Bridge. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

## Scripting Bridge Approach

With [ScriptingBridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html), create an `SBApplication` instance with [applicationWithProcessIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scriptingbridge/sbapplication/1588085-applicationwithprocessidentifier) and then you can call the bridged AppleScript methods on the process of your choice.

> ## Overview
>
> Scripting Bridge is a technology that lets you control scriptable Apple and third-party applications using standard Objective-C syntax. Introduced in OS X version 10.5 (Leopard), the Scripting Bridge framework dynamically implements an Objective-C bridge to OSA-compliant applications—that is, applications having a scripting interface (usually defined in a sdef file). As part of this implementation, it generates Objective-C class implementations of the classes it finds in the scripting interface, including objects and methods representing properties, elements, commands, and so on. The objects are derived from classes defined in the Scripting Bridge framework.

## AppleScript Approach

A [discussion on MacScripter](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=17677) suggests this approach:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set myPID to unix id of process "TextEdit"
    -- ...for every matching process
    -- set myPIDs to the unix id of processes whose name is "TextEdit"

    set myProcess to first process whose unix id is myPID
    set the frontmost of myProcess to true
end tell
```

See also: [How to activate Mac OS X application with a given process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296812/how-to-activate-mac-os-x-application-with-a-given-process-id)

Comment: @grahm-miln Thanks! That does set the targeted PID to the frontmost, but looks like running a `tell application appName` after that still targets whichever instance was run first, not the frontmost. Is there a way to then call that processes' application with a `tell application` call after you identified it?

Comment: Does `tell application (path to frontmost application as text) ...` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613293/how-to-get-name-of-frontmost-app-with-applescript-and-use-it-to-get-the-filepath#17615537 work?

Comment: I keep getting the error: `Expected end of line but found “"”.` in my script string when I try that method: 

`tell application (path to frontmost application as text) to DoScript "alert()"`

Even if I got that method working, not sure if it would solve the problem since the path would be the same for both instances of the application...

Comment: You should be able to target the process ID directly within the System Events tell block. `tell (process ID myPID) to ...`

Comment: @PatrickWynne Hmm, couldn't get that to work, `tell (process id 54287) to DoScript "alert()"`, but I think I'm really close. This code doesn't work, but this is basically what I need it to do: `tell application (whose process unix id is 54287) to DoScript "alert()"` Any other ideas?